# calling function as SELECT field in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-14

I'd like to call a function (that returns a single string) as a field of a SELECT statement.
This is my function:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION getData(text) RETURNS text
    AS $$ (select myField from myTable) $$ 
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

Of course `select myField from myTable` is more complicated, but returns a single string (text). There is logic in the select statement in the function that cannot be implemented (at least I can't) in a join where I am going to use it.
The logic is: join some tables and order by multiple fields and return the first record.

Then I would like to call the function in this way:

```
select myField1,
getData(myField1) as computated_field
from anotherTable
```

so that the `computatedField` is easily fetched instead of joining (I need only one record for each row) and with JOIN I would join many records, and I only need one.

All I get is:

```
ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "anotherTable"
```

Is there another way to do this? Or is it that this is not the way to use functions and there must be another instrument for it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you're looking for dynamic sql.

Comment: A JOIN is most likely still faster then this extremely slow row-by-row processing that you impose through the function. Besides: the function's query will read the value of an undefined rows from the table

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. That is not possible with function as I supposed, but it should have been obvious because it is not a programming language.

I left-joined the table two times on different conditions and `coalesced` the results.

Another version would have been to use a `Select` as a field with an `EXISTS` condition, that was really weird to see.